# Unable to upload to google app engine blobstore using custom URL

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Uploads were working fine until July 26th, when uploads suddenly failed when using the custom URL. When we go to our app at our-app-name.appspot.com and try the upload it works, but when we go to our-app-name.com we get a message saying the connection was suddenly closed by the host. So, going to our-app-name.appspot.com and calling the following works:

```
blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
```

But calling that command on our-app-name.com results in the connection sudden closed when we try to upload to that url (we don't even see the request in our logs). Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: This looks like a bug report rather than a question, so please file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list. Please also include your appid, what browser/tool are you using to upload the file and what is the error you are seeing.

Comment: This is not really a question but a bug report.

Comment: Thanks. I've created the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9780